# The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+3}}$ Is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+3}}$ convergent?

If we check using comparison, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+3}}\leq \frac{1}{n^\frac{3}{2}}$

Since  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^\frac{3}{2}}$ is convergent so this series convergent

Comment: Your comparison is correct, the series converges.

Comment: For completeness (if you want to be picky) you should state that your series is non-negative

Answer (score 0):

It's $\displaystyle 0<(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1.5}}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{1.5}}<1$ .

It follows $\displaystyle 0<\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+3}}<\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1.5}}<\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}-1}$.